# Laravel Passport OAuth not redirecting to login page

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I've been wrestling with this for about 5 hours now...passport works just fine in my development environment. But on my production machine (pulling git same version as dev) I am getting a json response of:

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated.","status_code":500}
```

The url I am visiting is

```
[mydomain.com]/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=1&redirect_uri=[redirect uri here]&scope=*&state=[encrypted value here]&user_locale=en-US
```

I would expect to see the login page instead of this JSON response.
I have already tried clearing cache, cookies, `passport:install`, `passport:keys`.

I have also done a `dd()` inside the `Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize` and it is not even being called which means it is not calling the proper controller method possibly?

Anyone have any ideas?

Laravel version 5.8.30
Passport version 4.0.3

```php
//AuthServiceProvider.php

public function boot() { 
  $this->registerPolicies();        
  Passport::routes();
  Passport::enableImplicitGrant();  
}
```

Comment: Is there anything helpful in you logs about the 500?

Comment: @Bryan not a thing...I've looked in laravel logs, and checked error_log php locations. Nothing. It is originally thrown from the 'auth' middleware that comes from Laravel. But I think maybe it is being caught again and handle somehow bc in my dev machine it is thrown as well. But somewhere in the pipeline it gets redirected to the login page.

Comment: That could be the issue. The authorize url probably shouldn't be behind the auth middleware. You expect unauthenticated users to be hitting this endpoint right?

Comment: @Bryan ...exactly. except when I print route:list that route is connected to the laravel middleware not the passport middleware. Both on dev and prod

Comment: Can you show the code where you put the `Passport::routes();`? Also can you please show the configuration in `config/auth.php` for your api guard?

Comment: @Bryan auth config guard is set to token. I am using a JWTAuth package but the middleware is set in the api routes for JWTAuth so it's not affecting any web routes.

Comment: The config could be your problem. The docs recommend passport as the api provider. Might want to check that out.

Comment: @Bryan ok...just reconfigured everything so I could use the api guard as passport. Now config/auth.php is same as shown in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#installation). I am still stuck. I've tried using different middlewares included in the passport library but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry Mike. That's about all I can think of. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well...after about 48 hours of pulling my hair out I finally found it.

I had one thing set differently between my dev/local and the prod .env files. Something I had totally not even thought about since I originally configured it. It was the `dingo/api` package setting for `API_DOMAIN`.

It was wrapping the Laravel Passport routes in an exception handler because it had the same domain and the `api` guard. That exception handler was not actually letting the redirect to the login page go through and hence the

```
{"message": "Unauthenticated.", "status_code": 500}
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future :)